# unordered_map on Xcode 4.2

Tags: c++, xcode4.2, unordered-map

hi I'm trying to use unordered_map on a program compiled in Xcode 4.2 but the compiler doesn't recognize it, i tried:

```
#include <ext/hash_map>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>  //using this one currently

std::tr1::unordered_map<char *, Vars> elements;
```

Where Vars it's a class, also I'm doing this in the definition of a class, the problem its that the compiler prints an error saying:

```
No member named 'tr1' in namespace 'std'
```

im not sure whats going on , so i would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well it seems it was my mistake, I'm using the compiler tool generator Coco/R and it seem that at the source file i made a mistake with an include and that made the parser and scanner files having a bug, actually after that the include

```
#include<tr1/unordered_map>
```

and  using

`std::tr1::unordered_map<char*, Vars> elements;`

seems to work fine .

thanks  anyways.

Comment: what is `tr1` ? I don't have to use that when I include `std` objects like `vector` etc. But I too am having trouble "finding" the unordered_map